# How to remove line that not contains any string? Angular

Tags: javascript, string, line

I have a string message but I have to remove the line which not containing any string. Because it will add more space to message container.

```
console.log(str);
```

The string ouput:

```
hello
how are you?

what's going on?


bye...


....more empty line below
```

I want it to be like:

```
hello
how are you?
what's going on?
bye...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that by using `replace` function with a regexp.
Example:

```js
var str = "hello \n how are you? \n\n what's going on?"
console.log(str)
console.log(str.replace(/(\n)+/gi, "\n"))
```